# Mongoid query with AND and OR condition

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I am using a MongoDB for a new app I am creating and I only need certain data from it. I require the following fields: current (boolean), position, sector, and name. The position field is populated with one of four values - "cash, SPVR, OFF, and training", while the sector field has one of two values - "Break or Working". I want a query that will give me all records where the following conditions exist:
1. current = TRUE
2. Position = "SPVR" or "CASH" OR Sector = "BREAK" and
3. Name is not NULL

The problem I have is that there are hundreds of records that have a value of BREAK, but most of them do not have a value in the Name field. I don't want any records that do not have a name associated with them. So in that respect, in line 2 above, I'm guessing the OR could be AND?

This is mu current start at the Mongoid statement

```
get '/currentstate*' do
    StateTransaction.where( current: true, :position.in =>["SPVR", "CASH"] ).to_json

  end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm beginning to think this cannot be done in one query statement. There is nothing I've read that indicates it is possible. I can use any_of for the OR part, but then that leaves out the AND. I'll try another route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work

```
StateTransaction.where(current: true, :name.ne => ["",nil]).and(
  StateTransaction.or(
    {:position.in =>["SPVR", "CASH"]},
    {sector: "BREAK"}
  ).selector
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately, it didn't work. It appears that the query is still looking for records where the position is SPVR or CASH AND the sector is BREAK. If i change sector: "BREAK" to another field such as email: "xx@yy.com", then it will find me all records where both conditions are true(position = SPVR and email = xx@yy.com), instead of one or the other.

Comment: Works great! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Following is arguably simpler:

```
sts = StateTransaction.where(current: true, :name.ne => ["",nil])
sts.any_of(:position.in => ["SPVR", "CASH"], sector: 'BREAK')
```